OAUTH for Google Places API (New): Avoid having to grant Android automation tool Tasker access to my Google account after every restart
I am using the Android automation app Tasker (joaoapps.com) to control different APIs (Spotify, Poweramp, Tomorrow.io weather) for an Android device in my car.
I also use Tasker to control the "Google Places API (new)" to retrieve information about nearby restaurants, shops, gas stations etc. Authentification is via OAUTH. (I present the results in a Webview element which includes JavaScript).
My problem is that every time I restart the Tasker scene, I have to give permission for joaoapps.com/Tasker to access my Google Account (see images below).
This is problematic since my Tasker scene is shown as fullscreen blocking overlay and therefore I cannot see the Google consent screen which just popped up.
Is it possible to give permanent permission to this app without having to give consent every time?
Thank you very much for your help.
Greetings from Germany
Philipp



As explained in Use OAuth - Places API (New) only you need a service account for server-to-server interactions. That is the only flavor of OAuth 2.0 supported by Places API (New):

For example, the Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions, such as those between your application and a Google service. For this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved.


Thank you very much for your answer and sorry for my late reply.

I've been trying around with Google console for a while.
There seem to be 2 options for avoiding the Consent Screen:

Domain-wide delegation: For this option, the API calls would have to come from one domain (=internet address?). This would also require a Google admin account which I don't have (and seems to limited to website owners?). Can this work with tasker?
Google Workspace Marketplace OAuth client: contents will be visible to Google Workspace Marketplace. I don't understand the risks attached to this? Can it work with tasker? Could others access my project? Thank you Philipp


https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/service-account-overview is the only OAuth mechanism that (I know) works with Places API (New). Workload Identity Federation might work but I honestly have no idea (haven't had a chance to try it out). The others you mention are completely new to me, no idea whether they could/should work with Places API (New).
